# Angular 2 Testing - Component Instance is undefined

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I have a problem in testing in Angular 2.

```
describe('Spinner Component', () => {

    beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [SpinnerComponent]
    }).compileComponents());

    beforeEach(() =>  {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SpinnerComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('Should Create a Spinner Component', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        var compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;

        expect(compiled).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('Should not be running', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(comp.isRunning).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

The code above shows that the Spinner Component in the test 'Should not be running'. I do not know what causes this. I get an error in the console (Please see below). I have created the component instance on the second before each as seen in the code but it states that it is **undefined** when ran on the second test case. I need help. I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

[Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHVo5.png)

Comment: `compileComponents` should be done asynchronously. Maybe that has something to do with it. You should add async to the beforeEach. `beforeEach(async(() => ...))`. Give that a try and see if there's any difference. `async` is from `@angular/core/testing`

Comment: thanks for answering, @peeskillet, however, it still prompts the same error.

Comment: Would you be able to put together a complete _one file_ example I can copy and paste that will reproduce the error? That means the component in the example also

Comment: @peeskillet Here is a plunker link of the file and component
https://plnkr.co/edit/uPd02BHllEvgD7QrH8eq?p=catalogue

Comment: `comp.isRunning`. You have no `isRunning` getter in the component, only a setter. You should add a `get isRunning() { return whateverThisPointsTo }`

Comment: @peeskillet Ok. I will try. Thanks.